# Salvar email na pasta SENT, IMAP

Tags: php, phpmailer, imap

Estou tentando salvar os emails enviados pelo PhpMailer na pasta "Enviados", para que quem acessar o email veja o que foi enviado pelo sistema.

Consigo salvar na pasta *Inbox* com o seguinte código:

```
$mailbox = "{".$mail->Host.":143/novalidate-cert}Inbox";
$imapStream = imap_open($mailbox, $mail->Username, $mail->Password);
imap_append($imapStream, $mailbox, $mail->getSentMIMEMessage());
imap_close($imapStream);
```

Porém se eu trocar *Inbox* por *Sent*, nada acontece.
Como fazer isso funcionar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com a dúvida se a pasta realmente se chama *Sent*.
Utilizei IMAP para listar as pastas e descobri que a pasta se chama *INBOX.Sent*.

Utilizei o código abaixo para listas as pastas:

```
$mailbox = "{".$mail->Host.":143/imap/novalidate-cert}";
$imapStream = imap_open($mailbox, $mail->Username, $mail->Password);
$mailboxes = imap_list($imapStream, $mailbox, '*');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($mailboxes);
```

E o código abaixo para salvar uma cópia do email em "Enviados":

```
$mailbox = "{".$mail->Host.":143/imap/novalidate-cert}INBOX.Sent";
$imapStream = imap_open($mailbox, $mail->Username, $mail->Password);
imap_append($imapStream, $mailbox, $mail->getSentMIMEMessage(), "\\Seen");
imap_close($imapStream);
```

Como na função não vem o destinatário fiz a seguinte adequação:

```
$mailbox = "{".$mail->Host.":143/imap/novalidate-cert}INBOX.Sent";
$imapStream = imap_open($mailbox, $mail->Username, $mail->Password);
imap_append($imapStream, $mailbox, "To: ".$destinatario."\r\n".$mail->getSentMIMEMessage(), "\\Seen");
imap_close($imapStream);
```